# Performance issues using MapKit for SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, mapkit

I'm working with a SwiftUI view that contains a Map with numerous Annotations (ranging from 30 to 100). Alongside these, there's a specific annotation that changes based on the user's selection from a list. The list selection might change rapidly, possibly up to 10 times a second.

When the selected annotation is updated, it seems that all the annotations on the map view get reloaded. This results in high CPU usage and a significant drop in screen refresh rate, especially during rapid selection changes.

How can I optimize this to only reload the selected annotation in the map view instead of all annotations when the selectedAnnotation is changed?

Here's the relevant pseudo code:

```swift
@State var annotations = [MKAnnotation]()
@State var selectedAnnotation: MKAnnotation?

Map {
    ForEach(annotations.indices, id: \.self) { idx in
        let anno = annotations[idx]
        Annotation("", coordinate: anno.coordinate) {
            Circle()
                .stroke(.black, lineWidth: 4)
                .fill(.white)
                .frame(width: 8, height: 8)
        }
    }
                
    if let selectedAnnotation {
         Annotation("", coordinate: selectedAnnotation.coordinate) {
             Circle()
                .stroke(.orange, lineWidth: 4)
                .fill(.white)
                .frame(width: 16, height: 16)
         }
    } else {
         EmptyMapContent()
    }
}
```

### The minimal reproducible example

```swift
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct Point: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
}

struct MapKitIssuesView: View {
    @State var points: [Point] = []
    @State var selectedCoord: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Map {
                ForEach(points) { point in
                    let _ = print("reloaded \(point) at \(Date())")
                    Annotation("", coordinate: point.coordinate) {
                        Circle()
                            .fill(.black)
                            .frame(width: 4, height: 4)
                    }
                }
                            
                if let selectedCoord {
                     Annotation("", coordinate: selectedCoord) {
                         Circle()
                            .stroke(.orange, lineWidth: 4)
                            .fill(.white)
                            .frame(width: 16, height: 16)
                     }
                } else {
                     EmptyMapContent()
                }
            }
            .mapStyle(.standard(pointsOfInterest: .excludingAll))
            .onAppear {
                for lat in 30 ... 45 {
                    for lon in -137 ... -79 {
                        points.append(.init(coordinate: .init(latitude: Double(lat), longitude: Double(lon))))
                    }
                }
            }
            .onDisappear {
                points.removeAll()
            }
            
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    selectedCoord = .init(latitude: .random(in: 30 ..< 45), longitude: .random(in: -137 ..< -79))
                }, label: {
                    Text("Change Selection")
                })
                .tint(.white)
            }
        }
        
    }
}

#Preview {
    MapKitIssuesView()
}
```

Comment: What are your annotation objects? You are using `.\self` as the identifier. Are these class instances fixed or are they being reallocated with each refresh?

Comment: [Annotation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/annotation) and [MKAnnotation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkannotation/) are MapKit things

Comment: @Paulw11 the `\.self` refer to the index of each annotation, and the refresh of annotations is not relevant to that selection of  annotation.

Comment: No, it's SwiftUI. View are structs and are recreated when things change. SwiftUI ties to optimise things. To enable it to do this, it uses the identifiers to see what has changed and what hasn't. If your annotations all look like they have changed then SwiftUI will process them every time `selectedAnnotation` changes.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine These MKAnnotation objects is just a representation of coordinate. The reason why I use MKAnnotation is because the calculation unit of cluster algorithm is MKAnnotation, and it can cluster annotation to another object `ClusteredAnnotation` which is inherited by MKAnnotation.

Comment: @Paulw11 I agree with your opinion, but in my case, the `annotations` and `selectedAnnotation` is working separately and I'm sure these annotations don't change when `selectedAnnotation` changed.

Comment: Note, [MapKit is for SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mapkit_for_swiftui).
 
 To improve your display performance,
you could try using the [Observation framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Observation)
 (and [Managing data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/Managing-model-data-in-your-app))
 it has the added benefit of views refreshing only the parts that needs it.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Actually yes, I use the Observation framework to observe the change of annotations, they are managed in a specific object, but my question is why these annotations will reload even if they don't changed.

Comment: Ok, I was just reading 
 from [Managing data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/Managing-model-data-in-your-app),
 it says
 `When a tracked property changes, SwiftUI updates the view. If other properties change that body doesn’t read, the view is unaffected and avoids unnecessary updates.` I thought this could help improve performance.

Comment: ForEach with indices will cause major issues. It's not a for loop.

Comment: Yes, I missed that. Don't use indices with SwiftUI.

Comment: @malhal Thank you for your replying, I tried to make the Coordinate type conform to both the Identifiable and Hashable protocols, and use it own id, but it still doesn't work. I have provided MRE code in my question.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you for your replying, I tried to make the Coordinate type conform to both the Identifiable and Hashable protocols, and use it own id, but it still doesn't work. I have provided MRE code in my question.

Comment: Find use index it’s unsafe

Comment: you'll need to remove Hashable because its a value

Comment: @malhal Then it will complain "Generic struct 'ForEach' requires that 'CLLocationCoordinate2D' conform to 'Hashable'"

Comment: you need to make a struct and put the coordinate as a var inside it.

Comment: @malhal Tried that, but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: With my tests, I can confirm that using a `struct Point: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
}` and corresponding code changes, does not make any difference.
 The view (including the Map view) is re-rendered when the `selectedCoord` is changed, as expected.

Comment: Try `Map(selection:)` or remove the `if`/`EmptyMapContent` and do it like `.fill(isSelected ? .orange : .black)`

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine I have updated my MRE code in the question. It always print "reloaded" since I tapped "change selection". would you mind providing your code? thank you so much.

Comment: @malhal My selected annotation isn't included in the annotations array. In fact, these annotations are clustered by an algorithm, the selected annotation might be clustered in a ClusteredAnnotation object.

Answer (score 0):

This is my test code. Note that using `print` in a view and in a `ForEach` is not that usefull.

I'm on MacOS 14.2, Xcode 15.1, testing on real ios17 devices (not Previews) and MacCatalyst.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import MapKit


struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MapKitIssuesView()
    }
}

struct Point: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
}

struct MapKitIssuesView: View {
    @State var coordinates: [Point] = []
    @State var selectedCoord: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Map {
                ForEach(coordinates) { p in
                    Annotation("", coordinate: p.coordinate) {
                        Circle()
                            .fill(.black)
                            .frame(width: 4, height: 4)
                    }
                }
                if let selectedCoord {
                    Annotation("", coordinate: selectedCoord) {
                        Circle()
                            .stroke(.orange, lineWidth: 4)
                            .fill(.orange)
                            .frame(width: 16, height: 16)
                    }
                }
            }
            .mapStyle(.standard(pointsOfInterest: .excludingAll))
            .onAppear {
                for lat in 30 ... 45 {
                    for lon in -137 ... -79 {
                        coordinates.append(
                            Point(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(lat), longitude: Double(lon))))
                    }
                }
            }
            .onDisappear {
                //  coordinates.removeAll()
            }
            
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Button("Change Selection") {
                    selectedCoord = .init(latitude: .random(in: 30 ..< 45),
                                          longitude: .random(in: -137 ..< -79))
                }
                .buttonStyle(.bordered)
                .tint(.red)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing your code, I have run your code in my Xcode. I have noticed that each time I tapped "Change Selection", the orange annotation will display after a short delay, regardless of whether I'm using a simulator or an actual device. I suspect this delay is caused by the map reloading all annotations each time the selection changes.

Comment: yes, I agree with that. When `selectedCoord` changes the whole view is refreshed. I tried a few other things without success, eg having `let coordinates: [Point]` and populating it in `init()`.